# How do I alter the UI of a Gmail Add On from a callback?

Tags: gmail-addons

New to gmail add ons and have a question which I am sure is pretty basic: how do I change the UI of my add on from a callback function?

More specifically, I have a button which renders in a section on my card:

```
section.addWidget(
       CardService.newTextButton()
       .setText('UNSUBSCRIBE')
       .setOnClickAction(
         CardService.newAction()
         .setFunctionName('unsubscribe')
         .setParameters({email: sender.email})));
```

As you can see, I call a function called "unsubscribe" when it is clicked which in turn calls a 3rd party API endpoint. Upon the 200 response from that endpoint, I want to hide the "unsubscribe" button and show a message to the user stating that the unsubscribe request went through successfully. Currently, I don't know how to access the card sections so I am showing a notification in stead:

```
function unsubscribe(e){

  var parameters = e.parameters;
  var email = parameters['email'];

  var data = {
    "code":"XXXX",
    "email": email
  };

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://someurl.com', options);

  if(response.getResponseCode() == 200){

    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
       .setNotification(CardService.newNotification().setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO)
           .setText(email + " has been unsubscribed from future notices."))
       .build();    
  }

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
       .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
           .setType(CardService.NotificationType.WARNING)
           .setText("Something went wrong"))
       .build();

}
```

It would be much better to hide the UNSUBSCRIBE button on success instead and display a success message in line. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, we cannot dynamically update sections of the card. Hence, you cannot directly hide the button and display some message. But as a workaround, you can redraw the whole card(which won't include the button and will include the message) using [Navigation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/navigation) class and updateCard method.

If you havn't used navigation class yet, [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/navigation) link might be useful.